How to install vite in cpanel?
i'm making laravel-react app and tried to host it. i did the composer install, npm install. Then, i tried to npm run build but i got sh: vite: command not found
i notice there is no vite in /node_modules/.bin/
even though, there is vite in my package.json
{
    "private": true,
    "scripts": {
        "dev": "vite",
        "build": "vite build"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@headlessui/react": "^1.4.2",
        "@inertiajs/react": "^1.0.0",
        "@tailwindcss/forms": "^0.5.3",
        "@vitejs/plugin-react": "^3.0.0",
        "autoprefixer": "^10.4.12",
        "axios": "^1.1.2",
        "laravel-vite-plugin": "^0.7.8",
        "lodash": "^4.17.19",
        "postcss": "^8.4.18",
        "react": "^18.3.1",
        "react-dom": "^18.3.1",
        "tailwindcss": "^3.2.1",
        "vite": "^4.5.3"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "@emotion/react": "^11.11.4",
        "@emotion/styled": "^11.11.5",
        "@inertiajs/inertia": "^0.11.1",
        "@mui/icons-material": "^5.16.0",
        "@mui/material": "^5.16.0",
        "material-icons": "^1.13.12",
        "react-material-ui-carousel": "^3.4.2",
        "react-responsive-carousel": "^3.2.23",
        "react-router-dom": "^6.25.1",
        "react-slick": "^0.30.2",
        "slick-carousel": "^1.8.1"
    }
}

and this is my vite.config.js:
import { defineConfig } from "vite";

export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [
    laravel({
      input: ["resources/css/app.css", "resources/js/app.jsx"],
      refresh: true,
    }),
    react(),
  ],
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      "@": "/resources",
    },
  },
});

i also tried to npm install vite --save-dev but still no empty response when:
npm list vite
in local environment its working fine also
